# The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c#

This portion of code that is not working:

```
public void WriteNOP(int Address)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x90, 0x90 };
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        WriteProcessMemory(this.pHandel, (IntPtr) Address, buffer, (uint) buffer.Length, out zero);
```

Error: 
`The best overloaded method match for 'Send_to_Console_CSharp.Form1.WriteProcessMemory(SYstem.IntPtr,SystemIntPtr, byte[], uint, int)' has some invalid arguments`

Any guesses about the reason of the error?

Edit: I deleted the last argument, but now a new error pops:

```
No overload for the 'Writeprocessmemory' method, it takes '4' arguments
```

Comment: Look at the last argument.

Comment: Read the error message carefully.

Comment: 5 arguments, the last one needs to be an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Im new in C#, i dont know what´s overload, also, the command have 4 arguments.

Comment: If you're new in C#, then you're starting in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your method signature as below, last parameter is just a `int` type and not `out int` whereas you are passing it as `out` parameter and that to a `IntPtr` type cause `zero` is declared as `IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;`.

```
WriteProcessMemory(SYstem.IntPtr,SystemIntPtr, byte[], uint, int)
```

Your mthod call

```
WriteProcessMemory(this.pHandel, (IntPtr) Address, buffer, (uint) buffer.Length, out zero); 
                                                                                   <-- Here
```